# Guild in the presence of discord bot

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js

I am trying to put the guild in the presence of discord bot, but I can't get it, the version is v12 this is my code. example (Watching 76 servers)

```js
function presence(){
  client.user.setPresence({
     status: "online",
     activity: {
        name: "{len(bot.guilds)}",
        type: "WATCHING",
     
     }
  });
}
```

**Sample image**:

[image: Example image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're trying to show the number of guilds the bot is in.

```js
// Discord.js v13
client.user.setPresence({
  status: 'online',
  activities: [{
    name: `${client.guilds.cache.size} servers`,
    type: 'WATCHING'
  }]
)

// Discord.js v12
client.user.setPresence({
  status: 'online',
  activity: {
    name: `${client.guilds.cache.size} servers`,
    type: 'WATCHING'
  }
)
```

Alternatively, you can use [`setActivity`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setActivity) if you are not changing the client's status (as it defaults to `online`):

```js
client.user.setActivity(`${client.guilds.cache.size} servers`, {type: 'WATCHING'})
```